# How do I call the FileExplorer.java with a button from 2 available buttons?

Tags: java, android, button, call

I am still new to Java
I am trying to implement the [FileExplorer](https://github.com/mburman/Android-File-Explore/tree/master/FileExplore)! <<= link

I have 2 buttons, one of them is to call the ExplorerFile class. But it does not seem to work. 
My first button seems to work though.

The followings are my code (buttons):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Status = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.app_status);       

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED);
    filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED);
    filter.setPriority(500);
    this.registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);  
    DeviceInformationContext = this;

//Button1
    Button connectBtn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.connectBtn);
    connectBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
            myMucNil.Muc_Config(19256, (byte) 0x8A);                
        }
    });
    myMucNil = new MUC_NIL(DeviceInformationContext);   


//Button2
   Button getPy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getFilePy);
    OnClickListener pyList = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, FileExplorer.class));
        }
    };
    getPy.setOnClickListener(pyList);


}
```

I thank you in advance for your kind help, if you would like to guide me.

Comment: First check if the `onClick()` method is called at all (use debugger or logging)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code...

```
Button getPy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getFilePy);
getPy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FileExplorer.class));
    }
});
```

And remove following code.

```
Button getPy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getFilePy);
OnClickListener pyList = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, FileExplorer.class));
    }
};
getPy.setOnClickListener(pyList);
```

Also you need to *register* **FileExplorer.java** file in **AndroidMenifest.xml** file.

using following code you register.

```
<activity android:name="FileExplorer"></activity>
```

before **application tag** is over.

Comment: Hey, @Mr.Sandy thank you very much for the reply. I have tried that, but when I clicked on the button, it prompted me with 'Unfortunately The_App has stopped'

Comment: I think you not register "FileExplorer.java" file in "AndroidManifest.xml"

Comment: you need to register like: <activity android:name="FileExplorer"></activity>  before </application> tag